# swap two 2d array of floats

Tags: java, swap

I want to swap two 2d array of floats.

```
 float[][] bluePath ={ 
     {-.025f,-.303f},
     {-.025f,.05f},
     {-0.38f,-.215f}
}


float[][] greenPath ={ 
     {-.4f,-.23f},
     {-.55f,.03f},
     {-0.58f,-.55f}
}
```

After swapping I want following result:-

```
     float[][] bluePath ={ 
     {-.4f,-.23f},
     {-.55f,.03f},
     {-0.58f,-.55f}
}


float[][] greenPath ={ 
     {-.025f,-.303f},
     {-.025f,.05f},
     {-0.38f,-.215f}

}
```

please help me regarding this.

Comment: You can do it using a temp array. What exactly is your question here ? What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary vareiable and copy byte per byte.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < 2, j++ )
  {
    float fHelp = redPath[i][j];
    redPath[i][j] = greenPath[i][j];
    greenPath[i][j] = fHelp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
float temp;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        temp = bluePath[i][j];
        bluePath[i][j] = greenPath[i][j];
        greenPath[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```